# I can not scrape all the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can not get all url information from the specified site.
More data can be accessed from the pictures, I wrote the code here assuming dynamic javascript web scraping. Like I want Quercetins link or name but ı can not access.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()

url="https://foodb.ca/foods/FOOD00001"
page = Page(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print ("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4wPC.png)
[Found links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HSrv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium and it solved,problem was some parts of website loads after so you need to sleep then scrape the data.